# Automatically moving data to another tab based on criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Doc I'm trying to build. It's not this exact book, this all contains fake data, but the gist is the same:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12ebgFNCcRbJfgz6MS5XxcLCEv9vcEGw-0aUJrYmIqec/edit#gid=0

You'll notice that the first tab is called "Master". What I want Master to populate with is any time someone in one of the three sheets has a Grade of "Negative" or the "Follow Up" checkbox is checked off. So this would account for the data currently in the workbook, as well as any future data that gets added.

So the end result would be the "Master" tab looking like the picture below.

Is there a way I can do this?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon checking on the sheet you've provided, it seems like you already have the correct formula for getting the data from the other sheets to "master". The only difference with it and your expected output is the checkboxes.

If you want to use checkboxes instead of TRUE/FALSE even in the queried data, you need to put/create the blank checkboxes first on the Follow-up? and Resolved? and the value of those checkboxes will depend on the queried values. Please see screenshot below:

[image]

Please let me know if you have other concerns aside from the ones mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I was able to figure it out, but I do have another question: Is there a way I can rewrite this formula in a way that will accomplish what I'm asking it to do without having to specify every sheet it's pulling from? So let's say I create another sheet called Group4. Is there a way I can pull in it's information without having to add Group4 into the formula? Basically, pulling from a certain range in any tab that starts with "Group" or something along those lines?